# hard link to directory not permitted when root

Tags: directory

I'm trying to create a hard link to a directory as follows

```
root@...:/usr/share/tomcat6/logs# ln --directory /usr/share/tomcat6/skel/conf conf
```

It fails with the following error

```
ln: creating hard link `conf' => `/usr/share/tomcat6/skel/conf': Operation not permitted
```

What am I missing? How can I create the equivalent of this directory link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are hard links not allowed for directories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual page of `ln`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/ln.1.html):

> -d, -F, --directory
>   allow the superuser to attempt to hard link directories (note: will probably fail due to system restrictions, even for  the  superuser)

An application cannot see whether a hard link is a hard link or the original file path. If this is not a requirement, you can use symbolic links instead:

```
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat6/skel/conf conf
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a very bad idea, but you can do this using debugfs:

```
debugfs -w /dev/sdXY
debugfs: ln /usr/share/tomcat6/skel/conf /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/conf
debugfs: quit
ls -ld conf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).