# Why are hard links not allowed for directories?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, directory, hard-link

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to create a hard link for any directory, it fails. I can create hard links for files inside file system boundary. I know the reason why we cannot create hardlinks for files beyond file system.

I tried these commands:

```
$ ln /Some/Directory /home/nischay/Hard-Directory
hard link not allowed for directory
$ sudo ln /Some/Directory /home/nischay/Hard-Directory
[sudo] password for nischay: 
hard link not allowed for directory
```

I just want to know the reason behind this. Is it same for all GNU/Linux distros and Unix flavours (BSD, Solaris, HP-UX, IBM AIX) or only in Ubuntu or Linux?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/why-hard-links-not-allowed-to-directories-in-unix-linux

Comment: Try `ln -F <src> <dst>` and it _might_ work. Certainly, it used to work for the superuser in older versions of Unix. Does anyone remember whether that was UCB or System V? Yes, bad things could happen, but usually not.  As I recall, `rmdir` knew not to carry on deleting past a hard link. However, users could get confused and delete things in error.

Comment: @StevePitchers How can `rmdir` handle hard links in a special way? A hard link is just a normal link - but an additional one. It is not even easy to find out whether an unusual extra links exist without extra recordings.

Comment: Each node stores the number of hard links that point to it: the contents are only released once there are no remaining links. So `rmdir` can tell whether the directory has links from other places. Recursive removal, `rm -r`, must be coded with care, to be sure it will act correctly even should there be errors like "permission denied".  BTW, UCB = BSD, doh!

Comment: I have done `ln -F` on directories and have it work. But you don't dare delete the directory afterwards for fear of corrupting the file system.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

## Directory hardlinks break the filesystem in multiple ways

### They allow you to create loops

A hard link to a directory can link to a parent of itself, which creates a file system loop. For example, these commands could create a loop with the back link `l`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/a/b
cd /tmp/a/b
ln -d /tmp/a l
```

A filesystem with a directory loop has infinite depth:

```
cd /tmp/a/b/l/b/l/b/l/b/l/b
```

Avoiding an infinite loop when traversing such a directory structure is somewhat difficult (though for example POSIX requires `find` to avoid this).

A  file system with this kind of hard link is no longer a tree, because a tree must not, by definition, contain a loop.

### They break the unambiguity of parent directories

With a filesystem loop, multiple parent directories exist:

```
cd /tmp/a/b
cd /tmp/a/b/l/b
```

In the first case, `/tmp/a` is the parent directory of `/tmp/a/b`.
In the second case, `/tmp/a/b/l` is the parent directory of `/tmp/a/b/l/b`, which is the same as `/tmp/a/b`.
So it has two parent directories.
Even without loops, multiple hardlinks to the same directory will create ambiguous parent directories.

### They multiply files

Files are identified by paths, after resolving symlinks. So

```
/tmp/a/b/foo.txt
/tmp/a/b/l/b/foo.txt
```

are different files.
There are infinitely many further paths of the file. They are the same in terms of their inode number of course. But if you do not explicitly expect loops, there is no reason to check for that.

A directory hardlink can also point to a child directory, or a directory that is neither child nor parent of any depth. In this case, a file that is a child of the link would be replicated to two files, identified by two paths.

### Your example

```
$ ln /Some/Directory /home/nischay/Hard-Directory
$ echo foo > /home/nischay/Hard-Directory/foobar.txt
$ diff -s /Some/Directory/foobar.txt /home/nischay/Hard-Directory/foobar.txt
Files /Some/Directory/foobar.txt and /home/nischay/Hard-Directory/foobar.txt are identical
$ echo bar >> /Some/Directory/foobar.txt
$ diff -s /Some/Directory/foobar.txt /home/nischay/Hard-Directory/foobar.txt
Files /Some/Directory/foobar.txt and /home/nischay/Hard-Directory/foobar.txt are identical
$ cat /Some/Directory/foobar.txt
foo
bar
```

### How can soft links to directories work then?

A path that may contain softlinks and even soft linked directory loops is often used just to identify and open a file. It can be used as a normal, linear path.

But there are other situations, when paths are used to compare files. In this case, symbolic links in the path can be resolved first, converting it to a **minimal**, and commonly agreed upon representation creating a **canonical path**:

This is possible, because the soft links can all be expanded to paths without the link. After doing that with all soft links in a path, the remaining path is part of a tree, where a path is always unambiguous.

The command `readlink` can resolve a path to its canonical path:

```
$ readlink -f /some/symlinked/path
```

### Soft links are different from what the filesystem uses

A soft link cannot cause all the trouble because it is different from the links inside the filesystem. It can be distinguished from hard links, and resolved to a path without symlinks if needed.
In some sense, adding symlinks does not alter the basic file system structure - it keeps it, but adds more structure like an application layer.

---

From [`man readlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/readlink.1.html):

```
 NAME
        readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical
        file names
 
 SYNOPSIS
        readlink [OPTION]... FILE...
 
 DESCRIPTION
        Print value of a symbolic link or canonical file name
 
        -f, --canonicalize
               canonicalize by  following  every  symlink  in
               every component of the given name recursively;
               all but the last component must exist
        [  ...  ]
```

Comment: Why can't a soft link do all this?

Comment: @Tanay Right, it could help the expanation to compare it to similar cases with soft links. Ill try.

Comment: Exactly how does this pertain to only directories? The way I understand it, these problems are also a problem for hardlinked files too. Moreover, I see hardlinking as an easy way to change a given directory's permission to allow others inside, without having to allow them inside the parent chain too. Sounds _very_ useful if you don't have the ability to add/modify groups...

Comment: great answer, but then... how did Apple solve these issues for Time Machine ?

Comment: Sounds very interesting! But I know nothing about what the issue is - can you give me a hint?

Comment: Your "They multiply files" is also true for hard links to files—yet these are still allowed.

Comment: Can't you create loops anyway using FUSE?

Comment: @flarn2006 Good point. I assume you mean loop involving a FUSE filesystem and the underlying filesystem. Do you know what happens or have you seen it fail?

Comment: "They break the unambiguity of parent directories": Given that the parent directory is one up along the path, there should be no "ambiguity" in the context of your example. Does the example need to be reformulated?

Comment: I agree that loop avoidance is the traditional explanation but all software that can handle recursion combined with following symlinks (soft links) would be able to support loops in hard linked directories, too. The recursion would need only need to track equally many inode numbers as the depth of the recursion is. Even with 64 bit inode numbers and 100 directory levels deep loop you would need only 800 bytes to correctly detect the loop.

Answer (score 86):

"You generally should not use hard links anyway" is over-broad.  You need to understand the difference between hard links and symlinks, and use each as appropriate.  Each comes with its own set of advantages and disadvantages:

Symlinks can:

- Point to directories
- Point to non-existent objects
- Point to files and directories outside the same filesystem

Hard links can:

- Keep the file that they reference from being deleted

Hard links are especially useful in performing "copy on write" applications.  They allow you to keep a backup copy of a directory structure, while only using space for the files that change between two versions. Note that the implementation must first break the link (or modifications will apply to the original file, too!).

The command `cp -al` is especially useful in this regard. It makes a complete copy of a directory structure, where all the files are represented by hard links to the original files.  You can then proceed to update files in the structure (after creating actual copies of only these files), and only the files that you update will take up additional space. This is especially useful when maintaining multigenerational backups.

Comment: regarding the last paragraph, if you edit "copied" hardlinked file, the original file is also changed - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70531/cp-al-snapshot-whose-hard-links-get-directed-to-a-new-file-when-edited

Comment: This description of hard links is rather misleading. It's basically true that hard links "keep the file that they reference from being deleted", but that's just a side effect of hard links. It's certainly NOT true that you can create hard links in one directory, change the "original" file, and then expect the hard links to somehow point to the old content. In fact, the guiding truth of hard links is the fact that it's not a link at all, at least not any more so than the original "file", which is just a name pointing to a file. **A hard link is simply another name pointing to the same file.**

Comment: The backup idea is good and I actually use that a lot, but I think users should be warned that changing a file will also change the backup.

Comment: Heck, a symlink need not point to anything at all. `ln -s "Don't use this directory" README` is legitimate. In fact, if you think about it, a directory can be used as a relational database and not contain any actual files at all.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but if you're looking for a backup solution that leverages links take a look at https://github.com/laurent22/rsync-time-backup -- it creates point-in-time snapshots that will hardlink unchanged files

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question, and some info is plain wrong.

Comment: Hard links do **not** "copy on write".

Answer (score 71):

FYI, you can achieve the same thing as hard links for directories by using mount:

```
mount -t bind /var/www /home/user/workspace/www
```

This is very dangerous because **most tools and programs will not be aware of the binding**. I once did something like in the above example and then proceeded to `rm -rf /home/user`. Luckily, there was nothing relevant in `/var/www`.

Comment: I've used `mount --bind <src> <dest>`. Use with care not to wipe the `src` ;)

Comment: I get: `mount: unknown filesystem type 'bind'`

Comment: on Busybox, it it `mount -o bind src dest`

Comment: @MatM same with Debian

Comment: If you only need to mount for read, you can set permissions on the mount point and avoid the `rm -rf` problem. https://superuser.com/questions/320415/linux-mount-device-with-specific-user-rights

Comment: Good, but ("recursive) mounts are not capable/allowed, of breaking the filesystem similarly as hardlinks?

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Wrong command-line option, `-t` wants fstype which `bind` is not, either use `-o bind` or `--bind`. You should correct this answer.

Answer (score 23):

The reason hard-linking directories is not allowed is a little technical.  Essentially, [they break the file-system structure](http://web.archive.org/web/20161008080319/http://en.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue93/tag/2.html). You should generally not use hard links anyway. Symbolic links allow most of the same functionality without causing problems (e.g `ln -s target link`).

Comment: Hard links have good use cases. Saying you should generally not use them is a little too broad.

Comment: +2 for providing the link that actually answers the OP's question (and mine), -1 for emitting an opinion ("You should generally not use hard links anyway" - if it had links to support it, it would be ok). Which was good, because I can't give +2 anyway. ;D

Comment: Try to summarize the contents of the link in the answer, and keep the link as a reference. This a Stack Exchange good practice to avoid link rot, thanks.

Comment: @EliranMalka Maybe no filesystem structure was broken, but apparently a hypertextual one was

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a hard link.

A directory is essentially a collection of inodes pointing to the data blocks of the parent directory, `..`, the directory itself, `.` (for sake of sub/child directories having it as a super/parent directory), child directories, and files.

Hard links are not supposed to change the data in the data block(s) that the inode indexes.

A hard link to a directory would either need to add another parent directory (another `..`) inode, thus breaking the rule above (that hard links should not alter the data block indexed by the linked to inode), or it would need to cause the hard linked directory to differ from the original directory (it would have an inode to a parent directory that was not the apparent parent directory from the perspective of the user).

**Clarification**

Say you had a directory, dir-1a, with `/` as the parent directory. Then you hard linked it inside one of `/` child directories, dir-1b , but you did not add a second `..` to the linked directory (as this would change the data block).

Now if you looked at the hard link in dir-1b, it will have as its parent a directory that is not dir-1b but is instead root, `/`. This means that you can tell which is the hard link and which is the original.

Hard links are not intended to be differentiable from the originals.

This occurrence would have a knock on effect on processes that expect hard links to not be differentiable from the original files. Directories are designed to contain the inode to themselves and to the directory of their hard link (parent directories).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are good, but here's a simple practical reason. Let's say you have a directory named `fred` which has a bunch of files and subdirectories, such as:

- fred/barney/wilma
- fred/betty

Now you create a hardlink to `fred` named `homer`. Then you execute `rm -rf fred`. You then try `cd homer/barney/wilma` only to be told that `homer/barney/wilma` does not exist. Then you try to open `homer/betty`, and that's gone, too! In fact, `homer` is completely empty!

Why? Well, what does `rm -rf` do? It deletes not only the directory, but the contents of the directory. So the first thing it does is delete `fred/barney/wilma`, then it deletes `fred/barney`, and then it deletes `fred/betty`. Since `fred` and `homer` are two names for the same object, another way of putting it is it deletes `homer/barney/wilma`, then `homer/barney`, then `homer/betty`. Deleting the contents of `fred` means deleting the contents of `homer`.

Why does `rm -rf` delete all the files like this? Imagine what would happen if `fred` *didn't* have a hardlink before you deleted it. Then the files `barney/wilma` and `betty` would become orphaned and take up space with no way to remove them except to run a filesystem cleanup tool that looks for orphaned files.

Now, a hardlink-aware version of `rm` could be written that does not delete a directory's contents if a hardlink to that directory exists, but you'd also have to make sure that any other program that can delete directories is hardlink aware. I think that's a disaster waiting to happen, and the benefits are rather questionable. It also means that hardlinks no longer Just Work™ the way they do in a standard Unix filesystem.