# How to circumvent hard link creation permission to directories on the same file system

Tags: kernel, permissions, directory, ext4, symbolic-link

I'm well aware of the difference between [symbolic and hard](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ln.1.html) links.
I'm also aware of the dangers of [creating hard links to directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories).

**Nevertheless, I'm *insisting* on creating a hard link *to a directory and all of its subdirectories* (on the same partition).**

However, the following does not work:

```
root@fab-ux:/home/fab-user/Public
# ln --directory ../Documents/CV/ CV
ln: failed to create hard link ‘CV’ => ‘../Documents/CV/’: Operation not permitted
```

*Is there a kernel/File System (Running on EXT4) parameter that will allow me to accomplish this foolishness?*

<sub>Yes, I can mount bind, can hard link individual files through a cron job, ... But the point is that I want both the convenience of physically only one directory *and* all its files and the convenience of only uploading certain hard-linked directories in my Public directory to the cloud and the cloud software detects symbolic links and doesn't support them *and most important of all:* I'm running Ubuntu! Not OSX nor Windows: I want the system to do what *I* want!</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you stay on a current kernel (it is a feature by the kernel rather then one of the filesystem) there is nearly no way around this limitations.

> ### Limitations of hard links
>
> To prevent loops in the filesystem, and to keep the interpretation of `..` (parent directory) consistent, many modern operating systems do not allow hard links to directories. UNIX System V allowed them, but only the superuser had permission to make such links.

### [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html) (excerpt)

...**Linking to a directory** is restricted to the superuser in most historical implementations because this capability may produce loops in the file hierarchy or otherwise corrupt the file system. This volume of **POSIX.1-2008** continues that philosophy by **prohibiting link() and unlink() from doing this**. Other functions could do it if the implementor designed such an extension...

---

Because there is no longer a system call like `link()` which don't checks the oldpath being a regular file the only way out may be creating a similar function to [linkat()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/namei.c#n4076) doing it your desired way.

Comment: Upvoted already, but waiting an additional 48 hours before accepting, just in case someone else has done this before!  **;-)**

Comment: Crap!  Forgot to accept!  (done)...  Remind me in 2 weeks to add the bounty I promised so long ago!  **;-)** (no access to AU all next week)

Answer (score 1):

You can not create hard links to directories in linux.  I have heard that OSX allows this for time machine to use, but not linux.  The closest you can do is `cp -l`, which will create a new tree of directories mirroring the original, but hard link all of the regular files.

Comment: Yeah, mount --bind is what I ended up doing...  :/

Comment: wrong. you can, its just not easy. this works for me: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/ext4.disk bs=10M count=1; mkfs.ext4 /ext4.disk; mkdir /m; mount /ext4.disk /m; mkdir /m/a /m/b; umount /m;sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; echo 'link /a /b' | debugfs -w /ext4.disk | sed '$s/debugfs:  $//' | sed '1d';mount /ext4.disk /m;`  - now /m/b is a hardlink to /m/a

Comment: @hanshenrik, now run a fsck on the volume and see if it complains that it is invalid and wants to delete one of the links.  You can do all sorts of crazy things with debugfs or otherwise directly tampering with the filesystem.

Comment: @psusi you're right, fsck was not happy about it. ```root@x-ratma-net:/# fsck.ext4 -f ext4.disk
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'a' in /b (1281) is a link to directory /a (12).
Clear<y>? yes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

ext4.disk: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
ext4.disk: 14/2560 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 1528/10240 blocks
root@x-ratma-net:/#
```